# How to use dynamic url's with testcafe fixture/tests

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

Taking this fixture I would like to set the `checkoutId` based on the result from the API call in the `before` fixture hook so I can use it to set the page on my tests

```
let checkoutId;
fixture`Check out as guest user`
  .page`localhost:3001/checkout/start/${checkoutId}`
  .before(async () => {
      await checkout.getCheckoutId(sampleData.cart)
      .then(id => (checkoutId = id));
});

// and here the rest of my tests based on the page
```

I tried [fixture hooks](http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#initialization-and-clean-up), [sharing variables](http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#sharing-variables-between-fixture-hooks-and-test-code) but I can't get it to work, checkoutId is undefined when requesting the page.

Is this scenario even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While TestCafe does not support dynamic URLs, you can call the [t.navigateTo(url)](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/navigate.html) action inside "before" based on your condition.

Comment: This answer is now a year old.  Has there been any change to this yet?  I'm not seeing an option to `page` that passes the context that would allow this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way:

```
const TEST_URL = "www.someurl.com"
fixture`jtc-b2c.testcafe`.page(TEST_URL)
```